# How to specify my unit and widgets tests in codemagic?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, codemagic

i want to integrate my unit and widgets tests in codemagic but always test run failed but in my vscode all are ok.

Here is how error appears in codemagic in test section.

[image: Like this appears in codemagic]

Here is my log tab in the error that appears in codemagic.

[image: Error in section test, tab log]

in codemagic in the section of Tests i have it like this:

[image: Config in codemagic test]

i am sure i am running in codemagic the correct branch and i am sure that all my unit tests and widgets tests are all ok in vscode.

like this i have the folder structure inside my test folder

[image: Structure of my test folder]

my tests are ok:

[image: Tests all ok in vscode.]

i dont have a premium account in codemagic.
any help appreciate it.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: can you also add information from `Log` tab of Testing step? to see what exact command is being executed

Comment: i have already edited it to show the log tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log and error message are very clear: in test arguments you should provide `test ./test` value